# Exception in thread "Game" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Please run the JVM with -XstartOnFirstThread

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, macos, lwjgl

I'am a beginner programmer and I'm trying to learn LWJGL following. I got stuck  with this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pUYjxeDNEs&list=PLlrATfBNZ98e5KBKGcL7ARy3DjstzI2TV&index=1) about reproducing Flappy Birds with LWJGL, the same of the guy who asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29439640/eclipse-exception-in-thread-game-java-lang-illegalstateexception-please-run).

I'm using Eclipse on a MacBook Pro Retina.

The problem is this

> Exception in thread "Game" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Please run the JVM with -XstartOnFirstThread.
>       at org.lwjgl.system.macosx.EventLoop.checkFirstThread(EventLoop.java:20)
>       at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwInit(GLFW.java:428)
>       at com.cherno.flappy.Main.init(Main.java:41)
>       at com.cherno.flappy.Main.run(Main.java:65)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Given by this code:

```
package com.cherno.flappy;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWvidmode;

public class Main implements Runnable {


private int width = 1280;
private int height = 720;

private boolean running = false;

private Thread thread;

/*window è un long perché lwjgl è un bindng di c in java.
 * Non esistono oggetti in c, solo id, ed ecco cosa abbiamo.
 */
private long window;

public void start() {

    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this, "Game"); //Punto (A)
    thread.start(); //Lo start fa partire il run di sotto
}

/*Inizializzo OpenGL qui dentro
 * OpenGL gira in un thread solo!! RICORDALO
 */
private void init() {
    if (glfwInit() != GL_TRUE) {
        //Handle it
        return;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);
    //Creo la finestra e mi faccio tornare il puntatore di C
    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Flappy", NULL, NULL);
    //Vedo se la finestra è creata
    if (window == NULL) {
        //MAke something
        return;
    }

    ByteBuffer vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    //Decido la posizione della finestra
    glfwSetWindowPos(window, (GLFWvidmode.width(vidmode)-width)/2, (GLFWvidmode.height(vidmode)-height)/2);
    //Setto il contesto per OpenGL
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    //Mostro la finestra
    glfwShowWindow(window);
}

public void run() {     
    init();

    while(running) {
        update();
        render();

        //Controllo se l'utente vuole uscire
        if(glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GL_TRUE) running = false;
    }       
}

private void update() {
    glfwPollEvents();
}

private void render() {
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    new Main().start();

}
}
```

The exception clearly asks me to start the jvm with -XstartOnThread argument. I do it going to "run > run configuration > arguments tab > vm arguments" in Eclipse and type "-XstartOnThread"; then i click "run" and I get this error:

> > Process:               java [569] Path:                  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
> >     Identifier:            java Version:               1.0 (1.0) Code
> >     Type:             X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:        eclipse [478]
> >     Responsible:           eclipse [478] User ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2015-08-06 21:41:32.956 +0200 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.10.4 (14E46) Report Version:        11 Anonymous UUID:
>   CBCCB665-9B7F-C8CC-612E-828FAD3AA52D
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 1500 seconds
>
> Crashed Thread:        20  Java: Game
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>
> Application Specific Information:
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   '+[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to
>   invoke on the main thread.' terminating with uncaught exception of
>   type NSException abort() called
>
> Application Specific Backtrace 1: 0   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff879b203c __exceptionPreprocess + 172 1   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x00007fff89d8676e objc_exception_throw + 43 2   CoreFoundation
>   0x00007fff879b1e1a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106 3
>   Foundation                          0x00007fff8e3178cb
>   -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195 4
>   Foundation                          0x00007fff8e29957f
>   +[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings] + 156 5   AppKit                              0x00007fff87f51c41 -[NSApplication run] + 928 6   liblwjgl.dylib
>   0x0000000121828a2e _glfwPlatformCreateWindow + 1406 7   liblwjgl.dylib
>   0x0000000121824d9b glfwCreateWindow + 443 8   ???
>   0x000000010977e954 0x0 + 4453820756 9   ???
>   0x0000000109770760 0x0 + 4453762912 10  ???
>   0x0000000109770760 0x0 + 4453762912 11  ???
>   0x0000000109770c4d 0x0 + 4453764173 12  ???
>   0x0000000109770c92 0x0 + 4453764242
>
> Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff8a578136 **psynch_cvwait + 10
>   1   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108c6a7b4
>   os::PlatformEvent::park() + 192 2   libjvm.dylib
>
>     0x0000000108c48504 ParkCommon(ParkEvent*, long) + 42 3   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c48dda Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 168 4
>
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108c48fc2 Monitor::wait(bool,
>   long, bool) + 246 5   libjvm.dylib
>
>     0x0000000108d4990e Threads::destroy_vm() + 80 6   libjvm.dylib
>
>     0x0000000108b15e43 jni_DestroyJavaVM + 254 7   java
>
>     0x0000000107d7b2b2 JavaMain + 805 8   java
>
>     0x0000000107d7d59c -[JavaLaunchHelper launchJava:] + 42 9
>
>   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8e2e1d00
>   __NSThreadPerformPerform + 293 10  com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff878cea01
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17 11  com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff878c0b8d
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269 12  com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff878c01bf __CFRunLoopRun + 927 13  com.apple.CoreFoundation 
>     0x00007fff878bfbd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296 14  java
>     0x0000000107d7e463 CreateExecutionEnvironment + 871 15  java
>     0x0000000107d7a1ac JLI_Launch + 1952 16  java
>     0x0000000107d804c0 main + 101 17  java
>     0x0000000107d79a04 start + 52
>
> Thread 1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a578136
>   __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   com.apple.Foundation             0x00007fff8e28df08 -[NSCondition wait] + 237 2   com.apple.Foundation
>     0x00007fff8e27ed9e -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions)
>   performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 823 3
>   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8e27e9e9
>   -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 131 4   java 
>     0x0000000107d7d7b5 JVMInit + 251 5   java
>     0x0000000107d7acf1 JLI_Launch + 4837 6   java
>     0x0000000107d804c0 main + 101 7   java
>     0x0000000107d7e0f5 apple_main + 92 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b8268 _pthread_body + 131 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b81e5 _pthread_start + 176 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b641d thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager 0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff8a579232 kevent64 + 10 1
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff8f674a6a _dispatch_mgr_thread
>   + 52
>
> Thread 3: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a578136
>   __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libjvm.dylib                     0x0000000108c6a7b4 os::PlatformEvent::park() + 192 2   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c48504 ParkCommon(ParkEvent*, long) + 42 3   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c48dda Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 168 4
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108c49043 Monitor::wait(bool,
>   long, bool) + 375 5   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108a6b1a6 GCTaskManager::get_task(unsigned int) + 56 6
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108a6bf85 GCTaskThread::run()
>   + 349 7   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000108c6e99e java_start(Thread*) + 246 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b8268 _pthread_body + 131 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b81e5 _pthread_start + 176 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b641d thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 4: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a578136
>   __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libjvm.dylib                     0x0000000108c6a7b4 os::PlatformEvent::park() + 192 2   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c48504 ParkCommon(ParkEvent*, long) + 42 3   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c48dda Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 168 4
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108c49043 Monitor::wait(bool,
>   long, bool) + 375 5   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108a6b1a6 GCTaskManager::get_task(unsigned int) + 56 6
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108a6bf85 GCTaskThread::run()
>   + 349 7   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000108c6e99e java_start(Thread*) + 246 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b8268 _pthread_body + 131 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b81e5 _pthread_start + 176 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b641d thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 5: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a578136
>   __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libjvm.dylib                     0x0000000108c6a7b4 os::PlatformEvent::park() + 192 2   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c48504 ParkCommon(ParkEvent*, long) + 42 3   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c48dda Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 168 4
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108c49043 Monitor::wait(bool,
>   long, bool) + 375 5   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108a6b1a6 GCTaskManager::get_task(unsigned int) + 56 6
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108a6bf85 GCTaskThread::run()
>   + 349 7   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000108c6e99e java_start(Thread*) + 246 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b8268 _pthread_body + 131 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b81e5 _pthread_start + 176 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b641d thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 6: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a578136
>   __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libjvm.dylib                     0x0000000108c6a7b4 os::PlatformEvent::park() + 192 2   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c48504 ParkCommon(ParkEvent*, long) + 42 3   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c48dda Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 168 4
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108c49043 Monitor::wait(bool,
>   long, bool) + 375 5   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108a6b1a6 GCTaskManager::get_task(unsigned int) + 56 6
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108a6bf85 GCTaskThread::run()
>   + 349 7   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000108c6e99e java_start(Thread*) + 246 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b8268 _pthread_body + 131 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b81e5 _pthread_start + 176 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b641d thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 7: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8a578136
>   __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libjvm.dylib                     0x0000000108c6b69e os::PlatformEvent::park(long) + 404 2
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108c48dda
>   Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 168 3   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c49043 Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 375 4
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108d9486a VMThread::loop() +
>   444 5   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108d942f5
>   VMThread::run() + 121 6   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c6e99e java_start(Thread*) + 246 7
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b8268 _pthread_body + 131
>   8   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b81e5 _pthread_start +
>   176 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b641d thread_start
>   + 13
>
> Thread 8:: Java: Reference Handler 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a578136 __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c6a7b4 os::PlatformEvent::park() + 192 2   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c62952 ObjectMonitor::wait(long, bool, Thread*) + 748 3
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108d17978
>   ObjectSynchronizer::wait(Handle, long, Thread*) + 202 4   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108b39a16 JVM_MonitorWait + 156 5   ???
>     0x000000010977e954 0 + 4453820756 6   ???
>     0x0000000109770c4d 0 + 4453764173 7   ???
>     0x0000000109770c4d 0 + 4453764173 8   ???
>     0x00000001097697a7 0 + 4453734311 9   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108ae01e2 JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*,
>   JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 1710 10  libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108ae0970 JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, KlassHandle,
>   Symbol*, Symbol*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 356 11  libjvm.dylib 
>     0x0000000108ae0b1c JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, Handle,
>   KlassHandle, Symbol*, Symbol*, Thread*) + 74 12  libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108b3305d thread_entry(JavaThread*, Thread*) + 124 13 
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108d49a6f
>   JavaThread::thread_main_inner() + 155 14  libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108d4b160 JavaThread::run() + 450 15  libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c6e99e java_start(Thread*) + 246 16 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b8268 _pthread_body + 131
>   17  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b81e5 _pthread_start +
>   176 18  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b641d thread_start
>   + 13
>
> Thread 9:: Java: Finalizer 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a578136 __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c6a7b4 os::PlatformEvent::park() + 192 2   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c62952 ObjectMonitor::wait(long, bool, Thread*) + 748 3
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108d17978
>   ObjectSynchronizer::wait(Handle, long, Thread*) + 202 4   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108b39a16 JVM_MonitorWait + 156 5   ???
>     0x000000010977e954 0 + 4453820756 6   ???
>     0x0000000109770c4d 0 + 4453764173 7   ???
>     0x00000001097709d0 0 + 4453763536 8   ???
>     0x00000001097709d0 0 + 4453763536 9   ???
>     0x00000001097697a7 0 + 4453734311 10  libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108ae01e2 JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*,
>   JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 1710 11  libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108ae0970 JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, KlassHandle,
>   Symbol*, Symbol*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 356 12  libjvm.dylib 
>     0x0000000108ae0b1c JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, Handle,
>   KlassHandle, Symbol*, Symbol*, Thread*) + 74 13  libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108b3305d thread_entry(JavaThread*, Thread*) + 124 14 
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108d49a6f
>   JavaThread::thread_main_inner() + 155 15  libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108d4b160 JavaThread::run() + 450 16  libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c6e99e java_start(Thread*) + 246 17 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b8268 _pthread_body + 131
>   18  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b81e5 _pthread_start +
>   176 19  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b641d thread_start
>   + 13
>
> Thread 10: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff8a57894a
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b640d start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 11: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff8a57894a
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b640d start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 12: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff8a57894a
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b640d start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 13: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff8a57894a
>   __workq_kernreturn + 10 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b640d start_wqthread + 13
>
> Thread 14:: Java: Signal Dispatcher 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a57351a semaphore_wait_trap + 10 1   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c6cd04 check_pending_signals(bool) + 128 2   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c69845 signal_thread_entry(JavaThread*, Thread*) + 57 3
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108d49a6f
>   JavaThread::thread_main_inner() + 155 4   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108d4b160 JavaThread::run() + 450 5   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c6e99e java_start(Thread*) + 246 6
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b8268 _pthread_body + 131
>   7   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b81e5 _pthread_start +
>   176 8   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b641d thread_start
>   + 13
>
> Thread 15:: Java: C2 CompilerThread0 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a578136 __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c6b69e os::PlatformEvent::park(long) + 404 2
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108c48dda
>   Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 168 3   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c48faa Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 222 4
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x00000001089b24b2 CompileQueue::get()
>   + 122 5   libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001089b26d4 CompileBroker::compiler_thread_loop() + 376 6   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108d49a6f JavaThread::thread_main_inner() + 155 7
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108d4b160 JavaThread::run() +
>   450 8   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108c6e99e
>   java_start(Thread*) + 246 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b8268 _pthread_body + 131 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b81e5 _pthread_start + 176 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b641d thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 16:: Java: C2 CompilerThread1 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a578136 __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c6b69e os::PlatformEvent::park(long) + 404 2
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108c48dda
>   Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 168 3   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c48faa Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 222 4
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x00000001089b24b2 CompileQueue::get()
>   + 122 5   libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001089b26d4 CompileBroker::compiler_thread_loop() + 376 6   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108d49a6f JavaThread::thread_main_inner() + 155 7
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108d4b160 JavaThread::run() +
>   450 8   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108c6e99e
>   java_start(Thread*) + 246 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b8268 _pthread_body + 131 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b81e5 _pthread_start + 176 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b641d thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 17:: Java: C1 CompilerThread2 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a578136 __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c6b69e os::PlatformEvent::park(long) + 404 2
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108c48dda
>   Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 168 3   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c48faa Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 222 4
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x00000001089b24b2 CompileQueue::get()
>   + 122 5   libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001089b26d4 CompileBroker::compiler_thread_loop() + 376 6   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108d49a6f JavaThread::thread_main_inner() + 155 7
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108d4b160 JavaThread::run() +
>   450 8   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108c6e99e
>   java_start(Thread*) + 246 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b8268 _pthread_body + 131 10  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b81e5 _pthread_start + 176 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a4b641d thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 18:: Java: Service Thread 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a578136 __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c6a7b4 os::PlatformEvent::park() + 192 2   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c48504 ParkCommon(ParkEvent*, long) + 42 3   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c48dda Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 168 4
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108c49043 Monitor::wait(bool,
>   long, bool) + 375 5   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108cc3b36 ServiceThread::service_thread_entry(JavaThread*,
>   Thread*) + 132 6   libjvm.dylib                   0x0000000108d49a6f
>   JavaThread::thread_main_inner() + 155 7   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108d4b160 JavaThread::run() + 450 8   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c6e99e java_start(Thread*) + 246 9
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b8268 _pthread_body + 131
>   10  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b81e5 _pthread_start +
>   176 11  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b641d thread_start
>   + 13
>
> Thread 19: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00007fff8a578136
>   __psynch_cvwait + 10 1   libjvm.dylib                     0x0000000108c6b69e os::PlatformEvent::park(long) + 404 2
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108c48dda
>   Monitor::IWait(Thread*, long) + 168 3   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c49043 Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) + 375 4
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108d49f42
>   WatcherThread::sleep() const + 126 5   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108d4add5 WatcherThread::run() + 243 6   libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c6e99e java_start(Thread*) + 246 7
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b8268 _pthread_body + 131
>   8   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b81e5 _pthread_start +
>   176 9   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b641d thread_start
>   + 13
>
> Thread 20 Crashed:: Java: Game 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a578286 __pthread_kill + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff91eecb53 abort + 129 2   libc++abi.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a8fda21 abort_message + 257 3   libc++abi.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a9259d1 default_terminate_handler() + 267 4
>   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x00007fff89d8a7d6 _objc_terminate() +
>   103 5   libc++abi.dylib                   0x00007fff8a9230a1
>   std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8 6   libc++abi.dylib
>
>     0x00007fff8a922b30 __cxa_throw + 121 7   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>     0x00007fff89d86898 objc_exception_throw + 341 8
>
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff879b1e1a +[NSException
>   raise:format:arguments:] + 106 9   com.apple.Foundation
>
>     0x00007fff8e3178cb -[NSAssertionHandler
>   handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195 10 
>   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8e29957f
>   +[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings] + 156 11  com.apple.AppKit                  0x00007fff87f51c41 -[NSApplication run]
>   + 928 12  liblwjgl.dylib                  0x0000000121828a2e _glfwPlatformCreateWindow + 1406 13  liblwjgl.dylib                  0x0000000121824d9b glfwCreateWindow + 443 14  ???
>
>     0x000000010977e954 0 + 4453820756 15  ???
>
>     0x0000000109770760 0 + 4453762912 16  ???
>
>     0x0000000109770760 0 + 4453762912 17  ???
>
>     0x0000000109770c4d 0 + 4453764173 18  ???
>
>     0x0000000109770c92 0 + 4453764242 19  ???
>
>     0x00000001097697a7 0 + 4453734311 20  libjvm.dylib
>
>     0x0000000108ae01e2 JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*,
>   JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 1710 21  libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108ae0970 JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, KlassHandle,
>   Symbol*, Symbol*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 356 22  libjvm.dylib 
>     0x0000000108ae0b1c JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, Handle,
>   KlassHandle, Symbol*, Symbol*, Thread*) + 74 23  libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108b3305d thread_entry(JavaThread*, Thread*) + 124 24 
>   libjvm.dylib                      0x0000000108d49a6f
>   JavaThread::thread_main_inner() + 155 25  libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108d4b160 JavaThread::run() + 450 26  libjvm.dylib
>     0x0000000108c6e99e java_start(Thread*) + 246 27 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b8268 _pthread_body + 131
>   28  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b81e5 _pthread_start +
>   176 29  libsystem_pthread.dylib           0x00007fff8a4b641d thread_start
>   + 13
>
> Thread 20 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):   rax:
>   0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x00000001217b7c58 
>   rdx: 0x0000000000000000   rdi: 0x0000000000004903  rsi:
>   0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00000001217b7c80  rsp: 0x00000001217b7c58
>   r8: 0x6e6f697470656378   r9: 0x00007fff91f16d70  r10:
>   0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206   r12: 0x00000001217b7de0 
>   r13: 0x00007fe7c0d223f0  r14: 0x00000001217ba000  r15:
>   0x00000001217b7cc0   rip: 0x00007fff8a578286  rfl: 0x0000000000000206 
>   cr2: 0x00007fff7722bfd8    Logical CPU:     0 Error Code:
>   0x02000148 Trap Number:     133

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are making another Main class with `new Main().start();`

Since you're in the main, maybe try `this.start();`

Also, if this don't solve your problem, try to make a second class containing all your Thread stuff and then do: `new MyThreadClass.start();` in your main.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your solutions but they didn't work. The first because you can't use this in a static function (the main) and the second one just leads me to the same error.

Comment: It seems the thread that should be the first is the 20, the one that crashed from the report I posted above! @Sid

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've gotten the flag correct ? At one location you say

-XstartOnFirstThread but then you supply -XstartOnThread argument. It might just be a typo but this is apparently a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149634/what-does-the-xstartonfirstthread-vm-argument-do-mean) on Mac.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, but I wrote it correctly on Eclipse. The problem is that the flag is set but it doesn't work. I've both toggled the button you find in "run>run config. > etc." and types by hand the string. I know there's a issue, but I can't get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

the flag dose normally work, there are peoples Extensive directions findable with a lot of google-fu for tracking down the exact pid of the exact thread running on your machine and checking to see if the flag is set. But as i am doing the same toutorial you are I have what you really want instead. Code that compiles......
(i have left as many comments in as possible , its a bastard compiltation of many peoples Lwjgl3 getting started toutorials....giving credit back as a great thankyou for them helping me smack OSX straight.....happy bird flapping.....which is by far one of the best totourials out on Lwjgl3.....[C]herno....love the work

```
package bird;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

import org.lwjgl.Version;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWKeyCallback;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWVidMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;





public class Main  {


    private static final int WIDTH = 1280;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 720;

    private static GLFWErrorCallback errorCallback;
    private static GLFWKeyCallback   keyCallback;

    private long window;

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean isRunning = false;



   /* public void start() {

        thread = new Thread(this, "Game");
        thread.start();

    }
    */





    public void run() {
        isRunning = true;

        System.out.println("Flappy " + Version.getVersion() + "!");

        try {
            init();
            loop();

            // Destroy window and window callbacks
            glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        } finally {
            // Terminate GLFW and free the GLFWErrorCallback
            glfwTerminate();
        }
    }

    private void init() {



        // Setup an error callback. The default implementation
        // will print the error message in System.err.
        glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback = GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err));

        // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
        if ( glfwInit() != GLFW_TRUE )
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

        // Configure our window
        glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // the window will be resizable



        // Create the window
        window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Flapping the bird!", NULL, NULL);
        if ( window == NULL )
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window, GL_ -F-_U-");



        // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
        GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        // Center our window
        glfwSetWindowPos(
            window,
            (vidmode.width() - WIDTH) / 2,
            (vidmode.height() - HEIGHT) / 2
        );

        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, new KeyboardInput());

        // Make the OpenGL context current
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        // Enable v-sync
        glfwSwapInterval(1);

        // Make the window visible
        glfwShowWindow(window);

        GL.createCapabilities();

        glfwInit();


    }


    private void loop() {
        // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
        // OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
        // LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
        // creates the GLCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
        // bindings available for use.

        // Set the clear color




        // Run the rendering loop until the user has attempted to close
        // the window or has pressed the ESCAPE key.
        while ( glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GLFW_FALSE && isRunning == true) {

            update();
            render();


        }
    }

    public void update() {
         glfwPollEvents();

         if (KeyboardInput.keys[GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE]) {
             glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE);
         }
         if (KeyboardInput.keys[GLFW_KEY_SPACE]) {
             System.out.println("Farfenugen");
         }    
    }


    public void render() {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window); 
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().run();
        }



}
```